# Mini.iso Install on to Diskless Machine with NFS Mounted Volume

Tags: installation, nfs

Is it possible to install Ubuntu directly to an NFS volume? I'd like to boot a diskless machine with a mini.iso image and run the installer. The only problem is I can't find a way to mount the NFS volume from the install/command line.

Has anyone done this before, or does the installer assume my machine has a disk drive?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OnNFSDrive) in the official docs.

Edit: it doesn't use the mini.iso image, but it shows how to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Casey maybe you can post the working solution as an answer?